# Trigger focus() on NavLink in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, focus, accessibility, react-router-dom

I am trying to trigger focus() on NavLink element using `ref` in order to achieve keyboard accessibility but am getting error that ref can't be assigned to stateless component.

One way to achieve my purpose is by using using  `document.getElementById('myId').focus()`.

But I am looking for a way to trigger focus method on NavLink without actually using DOM library and if it is even possible.

I want to focus NavLink from a list of NavLink that is being rendred inside map. Here is how my list looks like:

```
            <ul>
              {data.map((element, index) =>
                <li key={index}>
                  <NavLink
                    to={element.linkTo}
                    exact={element.isExact}
                    onClick={handleNavLinkClicked}
                    className={styles.AppMenu}>
                      {element.text}
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              )}
            </ul>
```

Issue when trying to use ref with NavLink:

```
Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.
```

Due to this issue getting following error when trying to call focus method.

```
Cannot read property 'focus' of null
```

Configs of the project:

```
    "react": "16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "16.4.2",
    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
```

Comment: can you show your component that u weant to trigger?

Comment: still not enough example, how is your component is stateless if it is class?

Comment: I think the error is because NavLink is stateless component. So, when `ref` is added in NavLink, the error occurs

Comment: i dont see where u add ref to NavLink

Comment: this is my working component and if ref is added, it won't work. I have tested adding ref here as well as a stanalone NavLink component

Answer (score 0):

u can do it on a tag like this...

```
function Comp(){
    const aRef = useRef(null);
    const triggerFocus = ()=>{aRef.current.focus()}
    return <a ref={inputRef} /*....*/ />

}
```

i assume its the same with the NavLink..

Comment: I am not using hooks but i have tried something similar for my class component. I have updated the question with the error that i am getting.